# Escoger una imagen aleatoria dentro de una galería con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me gustaría hacer una galería simple, con tres imágenes, y que el usuario al hacer click en un botón aparezca una de las tres imágenes al azar.
Podríais decirme que es lo que tengo mal en mi código, y el motivo por el cual no funciona?

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var galeria="";


                function inicio() {
                galeria = document.querySelectorAll("img")
                ocultar();
                galeria[0].style.display = "block";

                }

                function ocultar(){
                    $(galeria).each(function(element){
                    element.style.display="none";
                    });
                }

                function imagenRandom(){
                    var aleatorio=Math.round(Math.random()*4);


                    if($(galeria[0])==$(galeria[aleatorio])){
                        $(galeria[aleatorio]).style.display = "block"

                    }else{
                        $(galeria[aleatorio]).style.display = "none"
                    }
                   if($(galeria[1])==$(galeria[aleatorio])){
                        $(galeria[aleatorio]).style.display = "block"

                    }else{
                        $(galeria[aleatorio]).style.display = "none"
                    }
                    if($(galeria[2])==$(galeria[aleatorio])){
                        $(galeria[aleatorio]).style.display = "block"

                    }else{
                        $(galeria[aleatorio]).style.display = "none"
                    }    
               } 
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="inicio()">
        <center>
            <div>
                <h1>Galeria de imágenes</h1>
            </div>

                <img src="img/dembele.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/iniesta.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/messi.jpeg" alt="">

            <input type="button" onclick="imagenRandom()" id="verImagen" value="Ver aleatorio" >
        </center>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

tenias varios errores en tu código, lo arregle para que funcione como quieres, te lo dejo funcionando, saludos.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script>
            var galeria="";
                            function inicio() {
                             galeria = document.querySelectorAll("img");
                             galeria[0].style.display = "block";
                             galeria[1].style.display = "none";
                             galeria[2].style.display = "none";

                            }

                            function imagenRandom(){
                             galeria = document.querySelectorAll("img");
                                var aleatorio=Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
                                // alert(aleatorio);
                                if(aleatorio==0){
                                    galeria[0].style.display = "block";
                                    // alert(aleatorio);
                                }else{
                                    galeria[0].style = "display: none;";
                                }
                               if(aleatorio==1){
                                    galeria[1].style.display = "block";

                                }else{
                                    galeria[1].style = "display: none;";
                                }
                                if(aleatorio==2){
                                    galeria[2].style.display = "block";

                                }else{
                                    galeria[2].style = "display: none;";
                                }    
                           } 

                            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="inicio()">
        <center>
            <div>
                <h1>Galeria de imágenes</h1>
            </div>

                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/Number_1_in_green_rounded_square.svg/2000px-Number_1_in_green_rounded_square.svg.png" width=100 height=100 alt="">
                <img src="https://www.destinoytarot.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Numero2.jpg" width=100 height=100  alt="">
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/63/54/56/6354560a3604f0eba5976d6c5d885e9a.png" width=100 height=100  alt="">

            <input type="button" onclick="imagenRandom()" id="verImagen" value="Ver aleatorio" >
        </center>
    </body>
```

Comment: Dentro de la función imagenRandom, si se quiere comprobar si la posición donde se encuentra galería es la misma que aleatorio, mediante jquery, como se debería de poner? ¿Así: if($(galeria[0])==aleatorio){
                        galeria[0].style.display = "block";
                    }  

                    else{
                        galeria[0].style.display = "none";
                    }

Comment: Estas comparando un objeto con un numero, solo necesitas comparar el indice con aleatorio, como: `if(0==aleatorio){ //codigo..)`